# Apollo-client _mutation input type - data provided is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm working with Apollo-client. I'm trying to make a mutation on client. I wonder why when I do my mutation the data passed on the server is void?

Here my mutation type:

```
type: recipeType,
        args:{ 
            data: {
                name: 'data',
                type: recipeInputType
            }
        }, 
        resolve(parent, args) {
            const recipe = new recipeModel(args.data); 
            const newRecipe = recipe.save();
            if(!newRecipe){ 
                throw new Error("Error adding recipe")
            }
            console.log("recipe add with success!! ", args)
            return newRecipe
        }
```

Here my mutation request:

```
const addRecipe = gql`
    mutation addRecipe($data: RecipeInput){ 
        addRecipe(data: $data){ 
          id
          title 
        }
    }
`;
```

My react-apollo binder:

```
export default graphql(addRecipe)(Create);
```

My mutation call in my component :

```
onSubmit = (e) =>{ 
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.mutate({ 
      variables:{  

        title: this.state.title,
        ingredients: this.state.ingredients,          
    }
    })
  }
```

When console.loging my data provided in the form, my server returns:

```
{}
```

I can't figure out why.
I have tried to make the following mutation call:

```
this.props.addRecipe()
```

But my console returns:

> this.props.addRecipe() is not a function

Why this behaviour?
Any hint would be great,

thanks

Answer (score 2):

To reach your data, you have to re-enter the data title in your variables object. In my case :

```
this.props.mutate({ 
      variables:{
          data: {
            {...}
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/ shows a good example of this.